# Group by, Count and Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I am trying to translate the following query:

```
SELECT STATE, COUNT(*)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY STATE;
```

Into a lambda expression. I am using C# and EntityFramework, however it doesnt seem I can make it work. Here is what I have on my respository so far:

```
public IEnumerable<object> PorcentajeState(Guid id)
{
    return _context.Sates.Where(a => a.Id == id)
                         .GroupBy(a => a.State)
                         .Select(n => new { n.StateId , n.Count() });
}
```

Of course it doesnt compile and I am lost after googling for 2 hours . Could you please help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide the compiler error you get?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. The result of [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) will will be an enumerable of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`. The [`IGrouping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) interface only has one property you can access, `Key` which is the key you specified in the `GroupBy` expression, and implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you can do other Linq operations on the result.
2. You need to specify a property name for the anonymous type if it cannot be inferred from a property or field expression. In this case, you're calling `Count` on the `IGrouping`, so you need to specify a name for that property.

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<object> PorcentajeState(Guid id)
{
    return _context.Sates.Where(a => a.Id == id)
                         .GroupBy(a => a.StateId)
                         .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
}
```

The equivalent in query syntax would be

```
public IEnumerable<object> PorcentajeState(Guid id)
{
    return from a in _context.Sates
           where a.Id == id
           group a by a.StateId into g
           select new { a.Key, Count = g.Count() };
}
```

In either case, if you want the first property to be named `StateId` instead of `Key`, just change that to

```
new { StateId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
```

Comment: Thanks! So it would be g.Key.Field (In my case, STATE) . Correct?

Comment: @user2865100 I'm a little confused as to whether you want to group by `State` or `StateId`. Are they supposed to be the same field (just a typo)? If not, how do they relate to each other?

Comment: I actually masked it a little bit from my original code so most likely a typo. Sorry about that.
State is a description, I need to get the count of each description for all of those that match the Where clause. I need this in order to "feed" a PieChart using this : http://blog.platformular.com/2012/03/20/load-google-chart-by-ajax-using-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/.

This code is in my repository, and it does compile now with your help. thanks! I am now stuck at controller, but I need to take a look at it now that i've fixed this.

Comment: @user2865100 Well, glad I could help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

This one is good

```
public IEnumerable<object> PorcentajeState(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.Sates.Where(a => a.Id == id)
                             .GroupBy(a => a.StateId)
                             .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
    }
```

But try this.

```
public IEnumerable<object> PorcentajeState(Guid id)
        {
            return _context.Sates.Where(a => a.Id == id)
                                 .GroupBy(a => a.StateId)
                                 .Select(g => new { g.Key.StateId, Count = g.Count() });
        }
```